# Why text pasting to python REPL sometimes doesn't work after lanching phantomjs from selenium webdriver?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, phantomjs, read-eval-print-loop

Is it something related to text input IME in ubuntu or it is a phantom js problem?

Just a normal string from py files while I am learning step by step execution:

```
driver.get("https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-http-headers-is-my-browser-sending")
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '''/html/body/div[@id='holder']/div[@id='main']/section/div[@class='content']''').text)
```

it pastes half of it or just one letter: "p"
or `"print(driver.find_element_by_xpa"`

It works after python REPL restart, but after some time problem repeats.

Comment: Just a normal string from py files while I am learning step by step execution: driver.get("https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-http-headers-is-my-browser-sending") print(driver.find_element_by_xpath('''/html/body/div[@id='holder']/div[@id='main']/section/div[@class='content']''').text)

Comment: Try using ipython instead of python. Not a solution but might help

Answer (score 0):

You might be right about PhantomJS issues. 
When I was researching the ways to run tests headlessly, I saw complaints about Phantom's odd behaviors and noticed some myself.
So, while this does not answer your question, I would suggest to try alternative solution if you keep encountering problems like you mention. 
You might want to try running your tests in [XVFB](http://elementalselenium.com/tips/38-headless) .
This way you will still run tests headlessly but in the real browsers, ff, chrome, etc.